# How to get an element's padding value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, padding

I have a `textarea` in my HTML. I need to get the padding numerical value in pixels as either integer or float. How can I get it using JavaScript? I am not using jQuery, so I'm looking for pure JavaScript solutions.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

This will return the `padding-left` value:

```
window.getComputedStyle(txt, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left')
```

where `txt` is the reference to your TEXTAREA element.

The above works in all modern browsers and in IE9. However, it does not work in IE8 and below.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/yp6XX/

Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

---

Btw, just for comparison, this is how you get the same job done using jQuery:

```
$(txt).css('padding-left')
```

The above does work in IE6-8.

Comment: to get the numerical value, be sure to pass the result to `parseFloat`, i.e., `parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(txt, null).getPropertyValue('padding-left'))`

Comment: The 2nd arg on `getComputedStyle` is optional. You don't need it.

Comment: @user670839 is correct but failed to provide details. The second argument is used to target pseudo elements, such as `::after`. I.e. the 2nd argument may be emitted but using `null` is valid too.

Comment: Nope, this results in a String such as `"3px"`, i.e. including units.

Comment: For better documentation, here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: This will fail if the padding-left contains a calc()

Answer (score 19):

After a search, I found [this resource](http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element/) to do what you're looking to do.

They want you to add a javascript function:

```
function getStyle(oElm, strCssRule){
    var strValue = "";
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle){
        strValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(oElm, "").getPropertyValue(strCssRule);
    }
    else if(oElm.currentStyle){
        strCssRule = strCssRule.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function (strMatch, p1){
            return p1.toUpperCase();
        });
        strValue = oElm.currentStyle[strCssRule];
    }
    return strValue;
}
```

And then call the function like this to obtain the particular style:

```
getStyle(document.getElementById("container"), "padding-right");
```

Where "container" is the id of the element and "font-size" is the property name. If you can guarantee that all the CSS on the element will be inline then this solution would be cleaner:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.paddingRight;
```

Comment: That function doesn't work for shorthand properties like `padding`. You have to read the individual components separately. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/yp6XX/1/