# JavaScript get size of content box

Tags: javascript, dom

I was using padding to restrict the size of the content-box. I need a way to get the size of the content box width and hight in pixels.

I'm open to work around's like nesting elements, pseudo-elements, trying out something like flex box setups.

However, a vanilla JavaScript way to get these values is the subject of the question.

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lbzJi

Comment: and where is your code ?

Comment: What about `element.offsetWidth` and `element.offsetHeight` ?

Comment: This doesn't pertain to any specific code. Here is an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lbzJi

Comment: From [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227909/get-element-padding-value-using-javascript), you can do `window.getComputedStyle(box, null).getPropertyValue('padding-top'));`, with `var box = document.getElementById('box');` That would return '20px', which you can subtract from clientWidth / clientHeight. If you do that for all padding values you should be good to go.

Comment: @daniel-knippers Would you please post that as an answer, particularly the `window.getComputedStyle` part was exactly what I needed to do that math myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227909/get-element-padding-value-using-javascript); you can use `window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('css-property');` to obtain the value of a computed CSS property. In your case, you can use this for the properties `padding-left`, `padding-right`, `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`.

For example, to compute the height of the content box of your "box" div you can do something similar to the following where I assume the padding is specified as an integer (hence the `parseInt`);

```
function property(e, p) { 
    return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue(p)); 
}

var box = document.getElementById('box');
var paddingTop = property(box, 'padding-top');
var paddingBottom = property(box, 'padding-bottom');    
var contentHeight = box.clientHeight - paddingTop - paddingBottom;
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, you could try:

```
element.clientHeight    
element.clientWidth
```

-or-

```
element.offsetWidth
element.offsetHeight
```

depending on what you want, but we'd need some code to really help you out.

Comment: as demonstrated here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lbzJi These are not the desired values.

Answer (score -3):

Try this using jquery: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/shoun

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("pre").append("Total Height = " + ($("#box").height() - parseInt($("#box").css("padding-top"))));
});
```