# Some Css Property does not work with this Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to redirect users to another page, if the CSS properties on an element do not match.

Currently, this works:

```
<div id="mydoom">
    myDoom
</div>

<style>
    #mydoom {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: red;
        visibility: hidden;
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        if (
            $("#mydoom").css('visibility') == 'hidden' && // See if the visibility is hidden.
            $("#mydoom").css('position') == 'relative' && // See if the position relative.
            $("#mydoom").css('display') == 'none' && // See if the display is set to none.
            $("#mydoom").css('font-size') == '25px' // See if the font-size is 25px.
       ) {
           //do nothing
       } else {
           window.location.replace("http://example.com");
       }
   });
})
//]]>
</script>
```

It worked and redirect the page if I change any of that CSS properties to some other value, if i change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` then the page redirect to example.

However, when I try to check the `padding` property, it doesn't redirect.

For example:

```
<div id="mydoom">
    myDoom
</div>

<style>
    #mydoom {
        position: relative;
        padding: 12px;
        color: red;
        visibility: hidden;
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function() {
            if (
                $("#mydoom").css('visibility') == 'hidden' && // See if the visibility is hidden.
                $("#mydoom").css('position') == 'relative' && // See if the position is relative.
                $("#mydoom").css('display') == 'none' && // See if the display is set to none.
                $("#mydoom").css('padding') == '5px' // See if padding is 5px.
          ) {
              //do nothing
          } else {
             window.location.replace("http://example.com");
          }
     });
 })
//]]>
</script>
```

Now you see, I put padding property and set it to `5px` in JavaScript but write `12px` in CSS, now the page should be redirected but it cannot.

Why does the padding property does not work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery How to Get Element's Margin and Padding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420434/jquery-how-to-get-elements-margin-and-padding)

Comment: @Steve can you make the script for me, i dont know more about javascript, how to make it possible, i check that post but nothing to found to work...how to make my existing script to work with padding ...

Comment: Unfortunately, SO is not a script writing service. Take a look at the accepted answer on the linked question to see how to get an element's padding in jQuery. (Hint: you need to get a direction's padding, not the `padding` shorthand)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get element padding value using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227909/get-element-padding-value-using-javascript)

Comment: @Steve i also tried padding-left but it also not work..can you please share the code with me. thanks

Comment: Try this : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/w3j3fyx9/ . The padding property itself recognizes the top,right,bottom,left values. So in order to get a specific value for comparison, you need to specify the direction. Also , $(document).ready( and $(function() are same thing, so you do not need both of them

Comment: @DinoMyte glad it worked if we set direction, however, there is another problem. it does not work with color property: try color property, i set in css color:red  and set also in javascript but does not it worked why ?

Comment: It's because the css attribute in jquery would give you relevant rgb of a color , so rgb(255,0,0) == "red" would fail. Here's from the documentation "CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, " - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: @DinoMyte and why the display:block does not work ? it worked only if we use it in separate javascript to add only the display block property, but it does not work with that multiples..if you remove the display:none or change it to display: block it will not work, test it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but pretty sure in JQuery the shorthand for 'padding' is not always accepted.  Something more appropriate would be to ask for 'padding-top', 'padding-right'... and so on.
I will test it and get back here.