# angular2: ElementRef get CSS padding attribute

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

I am exploring the `ElementRef` object in Angular2 (Ionic2), and I cannot get a hold on the `padding` CSS attribute of an `ElementRef`.

For the following question, I won't give details of my files:  [my project]\src\app\app.component.ts and [my project]\src\app\app.module.ts. Please assume those work correctly.

I have this code in a Component under [my project]\src\pages\my-component\my-component.ts:

```
import { Component,  ContentChild, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Card, CardContent } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector:'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my-component.html'
})
export class MyComponentPage {
    // @ContentChild("ionCard") ionCard:Card;
    // @ContentChild("ionCardContent") ionCardContent:CardContent;
    @ViewChild("ionCard") ionCard:ElementRef;
    @ViewChild("ionCardContent") ionCardContent:ElementRef;
    constructor(public navCtrl:NavController){

    }
    ionViewWillEnter(){
        console.log("ionCard: ", ionCard);
        console.log("ionCardContent: ", ionCardContent);

    }
}
```

Then this html template in [my project]\src\pages\my-component\my-component.html, I have:

```
<ion-header>
...
</ion-header>
<ion-content >
  <ion-card #ionCard>
    <ion-card-content #ionCardContent>
    </ion-card-content >
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

When I look at the log  (given by the `console.log` in the `ionWillEnter()`) for `#ionCard` and `#ionCardContent`: Both of them happen to have for `ElementRef.nativeElement.clientWidth` the same value. And that is probably good, but I can see in my Chrome inspect console (thru the Styles tab) that the `#IonCardContent` has a `padding`. And the real usable space width in `<ion-card-content>` is: (`ElementRef.nativeElement.clientWidth` - `padding`). And I cannot find where this padding is in   `ElementRef.nativeElement` attributes.

When I look at `ElementRef.nativeElement.style`, all attributes have an empty string value (among them `paddingLeft`).

I have also tried with `ContentChild` (as you can see those lines are commented in my code, and corresponding import are on top of the file). Since `<ion-card>` and `<ion-card-content>` are not standard DOM syntax, I suppose it was worth a try. But in that case, I get an `undefined` in the log.

**Anyone knows how to reach the padding attribute of a ElementRef.nativeElement in Angular2?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227909/get-element-padding-value-using-javascript

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer Ok you lead me to a solution: [window object].getComputedStyle(ionCardContent.nativeElement,null).paddingLeft); gives me the padding left (with px suffix). Do you want to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Thanks to Günter Zöchbauer for this one).

The solution is: `[window object].getComputedStyle(ionCardContent.nativeElement,null).‌​paddingLeft;`

It gives the padding left with px suffix.

More input about the `getComputedStyle()` function in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227909/get-element-padding-value-using-javascript).